# Iteract with arrays from another contract

Tags: solidity

Does anyone know how can I read meanings of variables in the array from another contract ? For example:

```solidity
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Contract1{
  uint[] newData ;
  
  constructor(uint _i){
      newData.push(_i);
  }
 }

interface IContract1 {
    function newData() external returns(uint[] memory);
}

contract Contract2 {
    uint public newOne;
    function foo(address _addr, uint _i) external{
        newOne = IContract1(_addr).newData()[_i];
    }
}
```

This code has compiled success in the Remix, but I have an error when I trying call foo()

Answer (score 1):

`Contract1`.`newData` is an `internal` (default [visibility](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) when you don't specify it) property.

But the `interface IContract1` defines an `external function` named `newData()` (without the index argument).

---

You can modify the `newData` property to have a `public` visibility, for which the compiler autogenerates a [getter](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html#getter-functions) function (with the index argument).

Then you also need to update the function definition in the interface, so that it contains the index argument and returns just one item (and not the whole array).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Contract1 {
    // changed visibility to `public`
    uint[] public newData;
    
    constructor(uint _i){
        newData.push(_i);
    }
}

interface IContract1 {
    // added `_index` argument
    // changed the return value to one item of the array
    function newData(uint256 _index) external returns(uint);
}

contract Contract2 {
    uint public newOne;

    function foo(address _addr, uint _i) external{
        // changed the call to the getter function
        // instead of trying to access the property directly
        newOne = IContract1(_addr).newData(_i);
    }
}
```

Note that the `Contract1` `constructor` pushes the first item to the array, so you need to pass `0` (as for the first index) to the `foo()` function argument `uint _i`.

Repro steps:

1. Deploy `Contract1` passing it `123` as constructor param. Deployed to address `0x456`.
2. Deploy `Contract2`
3. Execute `Contract2` function `foo(0x456, 0)`, which will effectively set `Contract2`.`newOne` value to `123`.

Comment: Thank you, very good answer!!!